# How to store amount value excluding the currency symbol using selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

How to store amount value excluding the currency symbol using selenium IDE for example I am getting " $ 14.32" on my web page and I have to store only "14.32" , So can you please suggest me how to store that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the value from the page. Then use a `storeEval` to process that value with JavaScript functions.

```
store | path/to/element | currencyAmount
storeEval | parseInt(storedVars['currencyAmount'].replace('$', ''), 10) | amount
```

Comment: `parseInt`? What was I thinking? Anyway I'm glad `replace` worked for you :-)

Comment: Not a new point for StackOverflow, but in my words: Unless you employ something like String or http://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js instead of a JavaScript number (IEEE 754 double-precision, 64 bits in total with 52 bits (=13 hex digits) for fractional part of the value), you'll have round-off. In particular when you want one cent and JavaScript stores the amount as 0.01 = (+2^-7)*(1+(47ae147ae147ae1 base 16)/(16^15 - 1)), you're really storing the approximation (+2^-7)*(147ae147ae147a base 16)/16^13 = 0.0099999999999999984734433411404097569175064563751220703125